# Selenium Get popup and popunder currently open link

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

In my site when I search anything on homepage its open one **leaves behind window** and one *popunder* window.Using selenium I want to know its open correctly or not and also take this two window link.

I tried this but it's not working

```
public class Utility 
{
    public static WebDriver getHandleToWindow(String title){

        //parentWindowHandle = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getWindowHandle(); // save the current window handle.
        WebDriver popup = null;
        Set<String> windowIterator = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getWindowHandles();
        System.err.println("No of windows :  " + windowIterator.size());
        for (String s : windowIterator) {
          String windowHandle = s; 
          popup = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().switchTo().window(windowHandle);
          System.out.println("Window Title : " + popup.getTitle());
          System.out.println("Window Url : " + popup.getCurrentUrl());
          if (popup.getTitle().equals(title) ){
              System.out.println("Selected Window Title : " + popup.getTitle());
              return popup;
          }

        }
                System.out.println("Window Title :" + popup.getTitle());
                System.out.println();
            return popup;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you've launched only one WebDriver process, there will be only one WebDriver. It contains a list of window handles. You don't need to have multiple instances of WebDriver. If you want to go to the new window (or tab) and then go back to the main window, you should store the windowHandle of the main window somewhere in the `WebDriverInitialize` class. My example below shows how to store the windowHandle in the Utility class.

```
public class Utility 
{
    public static void switchToNewWindow(String title){
        Set<String> windowIterator = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getWindowHandles();
        System.err.println("No of windows :  " + windowIterator.size());
        for (String s : windowIterator) {
            String windowHandle = s; 
            WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().switchTo().window(windowHandle);
            System.out.println("Window Title : " + WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getTitle());
            System.out.println("Window Url : " + WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getCurrentUrl());
            // you may use .getTitle().contains(title) if you cannot predict the full title
            if (WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getTitle().equals(title) ){
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static string mainWindowHandle;

}

WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().get("https://www.rentalhomes.com/");
Utility.mainWindowHandle = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getWindowHandle();
...
WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().findElement(By.id("home-page-search-btn")).click();
// Switch to the new window
Utility.switchToNewWindow("San Francisco ...");
// Switch back to main window
WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().switchTo().window(Utility.mainWindowHandle);
```

Comment: WebDriverInitialize library problem in this code.can you suggest me how can I solve.